# Java Polynomial Multiplication

Tags: java, polynomials, multiplication

I am trying to write a simple code for polynomial multiplication. I think it is logical to take inputs as strings such as "3x^2".

Problem is I don't know what to do with the 'x's in it. How can I turn them into something that can be multiplied? What should the logic be? I am totally new in Java and I really need help.

For example:

```
String s = "x^2";
String s2 = "3x^5";
//(Multiply them)
result = 3x^7
```

Comment: IMO this is not a very easy to work with input format, it would need to be parsed and gives rise to strange edge cases such as multivariate polynomials and repeated exponents. Representing a polynomial as an array of coefficients (or similar) would remove such aspects and let you focus on the multiplication itself

Comment: I know that is really hard and unnecessary, I got the problem from a professor.He said that I can do it with what I know about java for now and I wanted to try.I did not do it  well but ıt works for now.I still think that this problem is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int[] multiply(String term1, String term2)
{
    int[] t1 = parse(term1);
    int[] t2 = parse(term2);
    int[] ret = new int[2];
    ret[0] = t1[0] * t2[0];
    ret[1] = t1[1] + t2[1];
    return ret;
}

public static int[] parse(String term)
{
    int pos = term.indexOf("x^");
    String coeffStr = term.substring(0, pos);
    int coeff = Integer.parseInt(coeffStr);
    String powerStr = term.substring(pos + 2);
    int power = Integer.parseInt(powerStr);
    int[] ret = new int[2];
    ret[0] = coeff;
    ret[1] = power;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I need a little bit of clarification.Is it available on negative numbers ? I did not get used to arrays much.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for multiplying polynomials in the format Ax^n, x^n or Ax.  I would put the terms you want to multiply into a List, and then parse the coefficients and powers into a HashMap, then use those to get you get your final result

```
    List<String> terms = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("x^2", "3x^5", "5x"));

    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for ( String term : terms ) {

        String coefficient = term.split("x")[0].matches("") ? "1" : term.split("x")[0];

        String[] exponent = term.split("x");

        String power = exponent.length > 1 ? exponent[1].split("\\^")[1] : "1";

        map.put(Integer.parseInt(coefficient), Integer.parseInt(power));
    }
    Integer finalCoefficient = 1;
    Integer finalPower = 0;

    for ( Integer coefficient : map.keySet() ) {
        finalCoefficient *= coefficient;
        finalPower += map.get(coefficient);
    }
    System.out.println(finalCoefficient + "x" + finalPower);
```

Comment: It looks advansed to me but I think I got the main logic.